# Filtering a json object in node/expressjs

Tags: node.js, express, underscore.js

I'm looking for filter a json file depending on user input from previous page using underscore in an express js app. This is what I've done so far:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var contents = fs.readFileSync("public/files/testFile.json");
var obj = JSON.parse(contents);
var gender = req.query.gender

var filtered = _.where(obj.elements, {gender: true}); // elements is the array I want to filter
```

The json I'm trying to filter is the following:

```
{
   "elements": [
   {
       "id": 0,
       "man": true,
       "url": "https://pbs.twimg.com/media/CfRi_u8aaW8AfQvI7v.jpg"
   },
   {
       "id": 1,
       "Woman": true,
       "url": "https://pbs.twimg.com/media/CfZ-8ikafWsAAngQGP.jpg"
   }
 ]
}
```

Notice that when I do the same changing the variable gender by "man" it works properly.Looks like using a variable for a search like this is not working. I have 2 questions:

1. What could I do to make it work?
2. Is there a better way to face the problem?

Comment: Please show us the JSON

Comment: Classical case of misusing keys as data carriers. The object's keys should not be called "man" and "woman". That's data. Call it "gender" and give it different values.

Comment: That would be a more eficient way to do it but still not solving the filtering problem ;). What I'm looking to is to add several new fields so I don't know if filtering like this is the best option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you try the following:

```
var _ = require('underscore');
var elem = {
    "elements": [
        {
            "id" : 0,
            "man": true,
            "url": "https://pbs.twimg.com/media/CfRi_u8W8AQvI7v.jpg"
        },
        {
            "id"   : 1,
            "woman": true,
            "url"  : "https://pbs.twimg.com/media/CfZ-8ikWsAAnQGP.jpg"
        }
    ]
};
var gender = 'man';
var filtered = _.filter(elem.elements, function(element){
    return _.has(element, gender) && element[gender] === true;
});
console.log(filtered);
```

I've hardcoded the value of gender here. You can read that from query in your app. I think the snippet is pretty much self explanatory.

Comment: This solve the problem and make it works. Thanks! Although the second question is still unanswered. Is this the best way to do it? I'm planning to add more variables to filter with...

Comment: If performance is the primary concern, I'd suggest that you create a hash of gender => element (on app startup maybe) so that you'll not iterate through the list on every request. Other than that, as others have mentioned, the key should ideally be gender with value as your data.

Answer (score 0):

You can build a new Json object.

```
var obj = {};
obj[req.query.gender] = true;
var filtered = _.where(obj.elements, obj);
```

Although I might suggest having a Gender field with values Male/Female, rather than Male:true or Female:true.

Comment: Using this is stopping the filtering from working. This call return the json object as it is.

Comment: Node is interpreting the gender variable as "gender", so its trying to filter your JSON by Gender field, which doesn't exist.